# How to change logging levels in logback.xml programatically

Tags: logging, log4j, slf4j, logback

I want to change the levels of the loggers that have been set in my logback.xml file . I can make the change manually but i want to accomplish by writing a piece of code. I am dense about this stuff and this is the first time i am working on logging . Any help on this front or on log4j or any such pointers will be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set logging level in your program as:

```
Logger root = (Logger)LoggerFactory.getLogger(Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
root.setLevel(Level.INFO);
```

Check the [logback manual](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/architecture.html#LoggerContext)

Hope that helps!

Comment: I am going this in scala so It goes like this 
             
             val MyLogger = LoggerFactor.getLogger("logger name")
             MyLogger.setLevel(LEVEL.INFO)

Comment: @Rags Did that scala code worked for you? I have no setter `setLevel` for that...